# Property `message` in error response body cannot be accessed | Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

#### Description

Using node I make a typical API POST request for which I have a `.catch` block with response variable say `err`. On error, the response body is returned as such (as seen from the Hyperledger Composer REST app)

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Payment needs to be of positive value)",
    "stack": "Error: error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Payment needs to be of positive value)\n    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:839:34)"
  }
}
```

#### My Issue

I am simply trying to fetch the `message` property from the above response and send it to the UI. But weirdly `err.message` **does not** give me the value I see inside `message` but returns the entire response body(same with `err.stack`).

So basically -- **`err`, `err.message` and `err.stack` returns the same output**

**How do I end up fetching only the value inside a property say `message` ?**

PS:

`err.statusCode` does return the correct value ie. "500".

`err.name` returns "StatusCodeError"(not "Error" that I see in the response)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so while not really a Hyperledger Composer question -   you could try is it response.getBody() ? This is just an example, not a code snippet to use

```
 var finalHost = "yoururl";  
  var r = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();  
  r.setHttpMethod("get");  
  r.setEndpoint(finalHost);  
  //r.setQueryParameter("locatenow", "true");  
  r.setBasicAuth(username,password);  
  var response = r.execute();  
  var responseBody = response.getBody();  
// If response is in json format, directly you can send to client. 
// If not then convert it.
return responseBody;  

// On client side 

var newoptions = JSON.parse(jsonstring);   
// returned resp.
```

You might consider something like Restify for error handling on UI side ?
See README at bottom here https://github.com/restify/errors/blob/master/README.md -> 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-errors - see this S/O here